# Sidetiq not working post Rails 5.0 upgrade

Tags: redis, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, sidetiq

I am in process of migrating a rails app to Rails 5 / ruby 2.4 from Rails 4.2 / ruby 2.2.2.  Most of the "issues" that I've encountered have been straightforward to address, but this one has me a bit stumped.

I have a number of recurring jobs that I send to the worker via Redis / Sidekiq / Sidetiq.  It used to work perfectly fine.  Now when I startup Sidekiq, my recurring-worker jobs don't appear to be "loaded," so basically they are not queued or executed.  This used to happen just automatically once I started Sidekiq, but maybe I need to explicitly instantiate these worker classes first now?  If I manually execute and delay (e.g., perform_in 1 second) a recurring-worker classes just once, then this class starts to be executed on the recurring schedule going forward as it should.  I do get errors show up in Sidekiq after I manually execute this "perform_in 1 second" job, but don't feel like this is the issue:

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.0/gems/ice_cube-0.14.0/lib/ice_cube/validations/minute_of_hour.rb:7: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.0/gems/ice_cube-0.14.0/lib/ice_cube/validations/hour_of_day.rb:8: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.0/gems/ice_cube-0.14.0/lib/ice_cube/validations/day.rb:9: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Here is what my recurring job class looks like:

```
class RecurringWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    include Sidetiq::Schedulable

    recurrence do
        weekly.minute_of_hour(0, 15, 30, 45).hour_of_day(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17).day(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    end

    def perform
        # Some Code
    end
end
```

My initializer:

```
Sidetiq.configure do |config|
    # Clock resolution in seconds (default: 1).
    config.resolution = 1

    # Clock locking key expiration in ms (default: 1000).
    config.lock_expire = 100

    # When `true` uses UTC instead of local times (default: false).
    config.utc = false

    # Scheduling handler pool size (default: number of CPUs as
    # determined by Celluloid).
    config.handler_pool_size = 5

    # History stored for each worker (default: 50).
    config.worker_history = 50
end
```

All of the gem dependencies seem to be installed with recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq 5 beta is out and is supposed to work well with Rails 5